# Free $R-module$ over an integral domain R that is not a field has finite length iff it is $0-module$

Tags: modules

Free $R-module$ over an integral domain R that is not a field has finite length iff it is $0-module$

I try to begin with the most navie case:If $F$ is free $R-module$ on singleton,that is,$R$,I attempt to prove if submodule $M$ is simple,then it must be trivial.But I can't see how to do it..Any hint will be helpful , thanks.

Comment: $R$ (as an $R$-module) has submodules which are the ideals of $R$. Take a nonunit element $0\neq f$ of $R$. Consider the ideals $(f),(f^2),(f^3),...,(f^n)$. That is a chain of ideals (submodules) of length $n$.  None of them are equal since $f$ is not a unit. Hence the length of $R$ is infinite. For the general case take a map $R\rightarrow M$, where $r\mapsto m\cdot r$ for some fixed $m\neq 0$ and use the same trick in the image of $R$ (which will be a quotient of $R$). I believe that should be okay.

Comment: @Levent thanks,I got it.

Comment: I said it will be a quotient of $R$ but since the module is free, it will be just $R$.

Comment: @Levent Sorry,I became confused again...Why  the series you construct is a composition series?

Comment: It is not a composition series but you also don't need a composition series. Length of a module is the maximum of the lengths of chain of submodules. Even if you define it as the maximum of the length of composition series, no problem. You see a chain of length $n$, if you refine it, the length increases.

Comment: @Levent The definition of length in my book is that we say an R-module $M$ has length $m$ if it has a finite composition series of length m..So if we want to use the construction to get a contradiction,we must prove the series you constructed could be refine to a composition series which has longer length than the length of $R$.Is my understand right?..

Comment: So the chain $(f^n)\subseteq (f^{n-1})\subseteq ...\subseteq (f)$ is a chain of submodules of length $n$. You can refine it to a composition series but this composition series necessarily has length larger than $n$. When you increase $n$ you see that composition series should be larger than all natural numbers, hence infinite (refining always increase the length of the chain, by definition). I don't say this chain is the composition series for the module, but the composition series for the module contains it, hence it does not have a finite length.

Comment: @Levent I find what confuse me is the things about infiniteness..The definition of composition series I learned is finite series..So is the Jordan Holder thm.All series appear in these statement are finite.So when I want to write down the proof rigorously,I always get stuck.For example,we could have series of arbitrary length,and you say it could be refined to compositions series which is not finite,but I can't see why this refinement exist..

Comment: Refinement exists by Zorn's lemma. But as I said again, you don't have to study infinite composition series to answer this question. It is enough to show that the lengths of chain of submodules is not bounded above.

Comment: @Levent .And even if we get a such refinement,I can't see why we could use Jordan Holder Thm to get contradiciton(since this the statement of this thm is about two "finite"composition series.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74058/discussion-between-levent-and-likemath).